# Doubletaptogo responsive menu not working on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, responsive-design

I am working on a website am having trouble with the navigation for mobile views. I am using this plugin: http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly. It’s supposed to require two taps in succession before loading a parent link, with a single tap revealing the child links. When I have a blank page with only the plug in and the logo, the plugin works perfectly.

The problem happens when I try to add anything above the row the navigation and logo are in.  When I add anything else above it, clicking on a parent link opens up the drop down for the parent link 2 above it. For example, when I click on “Workshops” in my navigation, the drop down under “News” opens up. This only happens only when previewing it on the actual device, on iOS7 in this case.

If I have only this as my HTML markup, it works:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-9 medium-5 large-4 columns" id="logo">    <a href="index.php"><img src="http://192.185.122.20/~aljlaw/images/pageLayout/JalozaA-banner.svg" alt="Jaloza &amp; Associates" title="Jaloza &amp; Associates"></a>

</div>
<div class="small-3 medium-12 large-8 columns">
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">    <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>
<a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" title="Home" aria-haspopup="false">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="Practice-Areas.php" aria-haspopup="true">Practice Areas</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Estate-Planning.php">Estate Planning Fundamentals</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Elder-Law.php">Long-Term Care Planning/Medicaid</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Veterans-Aid-Attendance.php">Veterans Benefits</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Probate.php">Probate &amp; Estate Administration</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Charitable-Planning.php">Charitable Planning</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Special-Needs-Planning.php">Special Needs Planning</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Estate-Tax-Planning.php">Estate Tax Planning</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Business-Planning.php">Business Succession Planning</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Medicaid-Planning.php">Medicaid Crisis Planning</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Asset-Protection.php">Asset Protection</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Estate-Planning-newsletters.php" aria-haspopup="true">News</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Estate-Planning-newsletters-Archive.php">Index &amp; Archive</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Estate-Planning-Consult.php" aria-haspopup="true">Becoming a Client</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Estate-Planning-Consult-Form.php">Request a Consultation</a>

                    </li>

                    <li><a href="Financial-Professionals.php">For Professional Advisors</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="Estate-Planning-FAQ.php">FAQ</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Estate-Planning-workshops.php" aria-haspopup="true">Workshops</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Estate-Planning-workhops-Registration.php">Workshop Registration</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about-Us.php" aria-haspopup="true">About</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="aboutUs-Andrew-Jaloza.php">Andrew Jaloza</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Contact-Us.php" aria-haspopup="false">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

But adding anything before that row causes the issue. 
Here is a jsfiddle to view an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t4YE5/

I’ve gone through other questions/answers here for issues with doubletaptogo, but none of them seemed to have the same issue. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: I know this isn't much help but the fiddle works great for me on iOS 7.1 using safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I think I figured it out. I wrapped the entire header in a div that was absolutely positioned for mobile devices only. Not sure why, but that worked.

So it looked like this:

```
<div id="header">
     <div id="header-wrapper">
       <!--Logo code-->
       <!--Navigation code-->
     </div>
</div>
```

And the css I added was:

```
#header-wrapper {position:relative;}
@media only screen and ( max-width: 40em ) /* small */ {
    #header-wrapper{position: absolute;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added the jquery:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#nav li:has(ul)').doubleTapToGo();
        });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

iv been trying to figure this out too..

Turns out that doubletaptogo.js only works when the nav is at the top of the page and there is no way around this; if the nav is below any other content such as header etc forget about using this script as it will always cause the nav to jump to the top of the page.

Comment: Try adding a wrapper div around it and absolutely positioning it. That allowed me to add other things above the navigation on the page.

Comment: that doesnt work, if i position absolute it messes everything up!